# Interpolation anomaly during drawing

Tags: c#, drawing, interpolation, antialiasing, smoothing

I have a problem with AntiAliasing smoothing mode and drawing.
Let say I have a signal with min and max values at the same points. 
So I want to display it to see where it "thicker".

So the method I use is to draw vertical lines and use antialiasing.
Here is the problem, the rising edge seems to be antialiased, but the falling not.
If I added some noise to the second signal the same thing observable.

#### Without noise

#### With noise

![With noise][2]

Can anyone point out what am I missing? Or this problem comes from somewhere else?

Code (moved from comments):

```
Bitmap drawBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Height, _
                               pictureBox1.Width, _
                               System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

Graphics drawGraph;

Point[] pts = new Point[] { new Point(0, 60), new Point(0, 59), new Point(1, 35), _
                            new Point(1, 47), new Point(2, 25), new Point(2, 35), _
                            new Point(3, 17), new Point(3, 25), new Point(4, 12), _
                            new Point(4, 27), new Point(5, 10), new Point(5, 22), _
                            new Point(6, 10), new Point(6, 11), new Point(7, 11), _
                            new Point(7, 16), new Point(8, 16), new Point(8, 24), _
                            new Point(9, 24), new Point(9, 34), new Point(10, 34), _
                            new Point(10, 46), new Point(11, 46), new Point(11, 59), _
                            new Point(12, 59), new Point(12, 72)};

using (drawGraph = Graphics.FromImage(drawBitmap)) {

    drawGraph.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    drawGraph.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias; 

for (int i = 1; i < pts.Length - 1; i += 2) {
    drawGraph.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), pts[i], pts[i - 1]); 
    drawGraph.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), pts[i], pts[i + 1]);
    }
} 

pictureBox1.Image = drawBitmap;
```

Comment: You don't need to include signature in your post - your user card is added automatically. Read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) for more details.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you're using to draw this?

Comment: And I'm sorry if it's a stupid question, but on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.smoothingmode.aspx) which is the first Google result I found, the example has antialiasing on a downward stroke but deliberately turns it off on the upward stroke. You're not doing something similar, are you?

Comment: Antialiasing switched on once at the beginning of the code. So thats why I dont understand why it seems not to use interpolation. Actually if I draw line which is not straight it will be interpoled well, but if I draw only vertical lines the falling edge and its environment is not antialiased.

Comment: Can you show us your code, so we can try to replicate this?

Comment: I will provide the result of operations with a given values in a point array. Just create a form and put a pictureBox on it and put this code to the constructor of the form.

Comment: Bitmap drawBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Height, pictureBox1.Width, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            Graphics drawGraph;
            Point[] pts = new Point[] 
            { new Point(0, 60), new Point(0, 59), 
              new Point(1, 35), new Point(1, 47), 
              new Point(2, 25), new Point(2, 35),
              new Point(3, 17), new Point(3, 25),
              new Point(4, 12), new Point(4, 27),
              new Point(5, 10), new Point(5, 22),
              new Point(6, 10), new Point(6, 11),

Comment: new Point(7, 11), new Point(7, 16),
              new Point(8, 16), new Point(8, 24),
              new Point(9, 24), new Point(9, 34),
              new Point(10, 34), new Point(10, 46),
              new Point(11, 46), new Point(11, 59),
              new Point(12, 59), new Point(12, 72)};

Comment: using (drawGraph = Graphics.FromImage(drawBitmap))
            {
                drawGraph.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                drawGraph.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                for (int i = 1; i < pts.Length - 1; i += 2)
                {
                    drawGraph.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), pts[i], pts[i - 1]);
                    drawGraph.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), pts[i], pts[i + 1]);
                }
            }
            pictureBox1.Image = drawBitmap;

Comment: Sorry to write like this, but I cannot answer to my question in 8 hours... Hope this helps to reproducate the situation!

Comment: Moved the code to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a pixel offset mode as well:

```
drawGraph.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
```

The `InterpolationMode` can be removed as it do nothing with lines (only with images when resized).

Comment: No problem. Just as a tip: you can use the DrawLines() method instead of DrawLine(). This can take your point-array and draw all at once.